# JavaScript how to change input value using public API and pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api

Could anyone explain to me why I cannot update my input value after clicking my submit button? My goal is to write a number, click the submit button and find the Pokémon with that number.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pokemon"></div>
  <button id="btn" onclick="testFunc(inputValue)">SUBMIT</button>
  <input type="text" value="" id="myInput">
  <script>
    const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    let inputValue = input.value;

    const testFunc = function(a) {
      const apiData = {
        url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/',
        type: 'pokemon',
        id: a,
      }

      const { url, type,  id } = apiData
      const apiUrl = `${url}${type}/${id}`

      fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.ok) {
            return data.json()
          }
          throw new Error('Response not ok.');
        })
        .then(pokemon => generateHtml(pokemon))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))


      const generateHtml = (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        const html = `
            <div class="name">${data.name}</div>
            <img src=${data.sprites.front_default}>
            <div class="details">
                <span>Height: ${data.height}</span>
                <span>Weight: ${data.weight}</span>
            </div>
        `
        const pokemonDiv = document.querySelector('.pokemon')
        pokemonDiv.innerHTML = html
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I will be grateful for any advice.

Best regards

Comment: #1) I don't see a change event handler for the input element.  #2) You're trying to pass in a variable that is set on page load, after the inline binding is created which is slightly odd.  #3) Instead of passing it in, why not lookup the input value in the submit method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `inputValue` retrieval inside the `testFunc` function.

```js
const testFunc = function() {
  let inputValue = input.value;
  const apiData = {
    url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/',
    type: 'pokemon',
    id: inputValue,
  }
```

The button's `onclick` only knows about itself, it cannot reference `input`.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");

const testFunc = function() {
  let inputValue = input.value;
  const apiData = {
    url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/',
    type: 'pokemon',
    id: inputValue,
  }

  const { url, type, id } = apiData
  const apiUrl = `${url}${type}/${id}`

  fetch(apiUrl)
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.ok) {
        return data.json()
      }
      throw new Error('Response not ok.');
    })
    .then(pokemon => generateHtml(pokemon))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))

  const generateHtml = (data) => {
    //console.log(data) <-- Slows down the result
    const html = `
            <div class="name">${data.name}</div>
            <img src=${data.sprites.front_default}>
            <div class="details">
                <span>Height: ${data.height}</span>
                <span>Weight: ${data.weight}</span>
            </div>
        `
    const pokemonDiv = document.querySelector('.pokemon')
    pokemonDiv.innerHTML = html
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pokemon"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="testFunc()">SUBMIT</button>
<input type="text" value="25" id="myInput"> <!-- Default to Pikachu -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I hope it will become less confusing in a few days.